# Export svg from Illustrator with or without artboard

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an Illustrator file where I created different shapes.
Every item will be animated separately so I export every item one by one.

The thing is that if I export the Illustrator menu asks me whether I want to export with the artboard or without (checkbox).

Up until this point I did it with the artboard so the viewbox size is added and the shaped are on their respected position within the viewbox. However I use this for online purposes so it has to be responsive.

After I'm done and created my entire animation I view it in Chrome browser and everything works fine. If I do the same in Firefox it works fine to but if I view it in Safari things stop to work proper.

I have animations that `scale` from the center of their `path`and `points` to the full size of the `svg`-element. After resizing the browser (not the frame but the content in the browser with `cmd/ctrl`+`-` these animations get different positions to scale to.

Can it be that because I exported with the artboard the center will always be the same? And if so if I don't use artboard how can I set everything to the right posistion?

Comment: Can you post a link to your site or somewhere we can see code markup or some visuals?

Comment: Yes please see here: http://www.michelvanboordt.nl. If you open it in Safari and `cmd/ctrl`+`-`the page you should see what I mean.